# What is the default hex value for the color of links in an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, colors

What is the default hex value for the color of links in an iPhone?

Ive set links to be a certain color for my site. For one section however I want to override this and set links to be the default blue that links are on iphones. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick test in the simulator:

```
R: 16 
G: 33
B: 204
```

is what I came up with.

You could do the same and adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

rgb(0, 132, 255) OR rgb(0, 122, 255)